# Strange offset in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[This site](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/) is scheduled for release soon, and I still can't figure out why the header is moved 17px down in IE8, and the IE developer tools have proven completely useless to this point, too. Anyone care to help out? :/

Comment: did you try a fixed height in css, for the header element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `<a>` tag around the logo block to `display:block`.

That should fix it.

You'll also need to remove the bottom border on this element, as this will show if it's set to `display:block`.